# Java Regex to find a exact match for a word

Tags: regex

I am trying to build a regex pattern in Java to find a exact match of a word.

For example, the word `hot` should be found in the first 3 strings but not in the fourth one.

```
hot in here
It's hot
how hot is it
a@hotmail.com --- > should not match.
```

I tried with the following regex but it does not work.

```
/(?: hot )/g
```

What would be the correct pattern ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use word boundaries `\b` around your pattern. A [word boundary](http://www.rexegg.com/regex-boundaries.html#wordboundary) does not consume any characters. It asserts that on one side there is a word character, and on the other side there is not.

```
\bhot\b
```